# HTTP Post oAuth 2 "Check the `grant_type` parameter"

Tags: flutter, http, dart, oauth-2.0, mediawiki-api

I am implementing the OAuth 2 authorization flow for Wikimedia in my dart app using the following code:

```
String jsonString = jsonEncode(<String, String>{
  'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
  'redirect_uri' : Uri.encodeFull(redirectUri),
  'code' : authCode,
  'client_id' : CLIENT_ID,
  'client_secret' : clientSecret,
});
String paramName = 'param';
String formBody = paramName + '=' + Uri.encodeQueryComponent(jsonString);
List<int> bodyBytes = utf8.encode(formBody);

Future<http.Response> response = http.post( 
  Uri.parse('https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/rest.php/oauth2/access_token'),
  headers: <String, String>{
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-Length" : bodyBytes.length.toString()
  },
  body: bodyBytes,
);
```

The response for this is:

> {   "error": "invalid_request",   "error_description": "The request is
> missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value,
> includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.",
> "hint": "Check the `grant_type` parameter",   "message": "The request
> is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value,
> includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed." }

It might have to do with the fact that the content-type is still JSON, even though I defined it in the header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or because the content-length is -1.

[Header Information from Flutter DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j2Ha.png)

[General Information from Flutter DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3udpD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the `Content-Type` header, you'll need to encode the parameters as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

To do this, you can change your code to something like:

```
String body = Uri(queryParameters: <String, String> {
  'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
  'redirect_uri' : Uri.encodeFull(redirectUri),
  'code' : authCode,
  'client_id' : CLIENT_ID,
  'client_secret' : clientSecret,
}).query;
```

The invocation is pretty much the same:

```
Future<http.Response> response = http.post( 
  Uri.parse('https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/rest.php/oauth2/access_token'),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length' : body.length.toString()
  },  
  body: body,
);
```

### Addendum

This can be a bit cleaner, combining both parts into the one invocation:

```
Future<http.Response> response = http.post(
  Uri.parse('https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/rest.php/oauth2/access_token'),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
  },  
  body: <String, String>{
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri': Uri.encodeFull(redirectUri),
    'code': authCode,
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': clientSecret,
  }
);
```

Note that the specific `Content-Length` header is not necessary, as this is calculated on send.

Comment: This still suffers excactly the same problems, only difference is the body is not utf-8 encoded.

Comment: Interesting. I don't have the appropriate client id etc, but running your code gives me the error provided, whereas running mine gives a different error: `{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}` which I more or less expected.

Comment: I removed the Content Lenght Params as in your edit (and removed the redirect uri as it is not required) and now it works. Thanks!